# Looking for free software to run Windows on a USB HD

Tags: windows-10, usb

I want to run Windows on a USB HD. To be clear, I don't want to install Windows from a USB HD, I want to run it there. I found many questions about doing that when search for duplicates, but none about running on the USB HD.

There's some commercial software [WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) that lets you do this. While it claims to be free the free version is crippled to the point you can't really use it.

Comment: [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard](https://www.disk-partition.com/download.html) says it can do this but doesn't recognise my USB drive.

Comment: [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) is another option but the "Windows To Go" options didn't apear for me

Comment: Update: AOMEI now working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) works pretty fine, you just need to select the proper `.ISO` file for Windows then the option for Windows To Go option appears.

> If you wish to boot the device in Legacy mode, select the “**MBR
>   partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI computer**” option. Or, if you wish to
>   boot it in the UEFI mode, select the “**GPT partition scheme for UEFI
>   computer**”.

[image]

Another good alternative is GImagex[enter link description here](https://www.autoitscript.com/files/gimagex/gimagex.zip)

[image]

This provides an older way of installing Windows on USB.

> With GImageX tool, simply extract the downloaded archive and run the
>   correct version of the program for your computer — the x64 one on a
>   64-bit version of Windows or the x86 one on a 32-bit version of
>   Windows.
>
> Click the Apply tab in GImageX. In the Source box, browse for the
>   install.wim file you found earlier. In the Destination box, choose the
>   external drive you’ll be installing Windows To Go on. Click the Apply
>   button and GImageX will image the Install.wim file onto the USB drive.

I have used all these methods but personally I prefer using [Win To USB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/), which is by far most straight-forward and easy to execute.

References

1. [How to Create A Windows To Go USB (Guide)](https://beebom.com/how-create-windows-to-go-usb/)
2. [How to Create a Windows To Go USB Drive Without the Enterprise Edition](https://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/)